# create and use index on OrientDB

Tags: indexing, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I create a database
Class: Tab,
Property:
    id (int unique)
    idTag (int)
    tagName( String)
    type (string)
    date (datetime)
    xy (Opoint) geospatial
    z (double)

I want to make an index to speed the query

If a create an index for 1 property (like idTag)

CREATE INDEX index_idTag ON Tab (idTag) notunique;

1/
Who can I query index_idTag and type  in the same query 
Something like 
Select from Tab where index_idTag= 10 and type=« Personne »

2/
I want to query an index (index_idTag), but return all information (id, index_idTag (idTag), tagName, type, date, xy, z)

Ty for your help

Answer (score 4):

with the index defined, the query:

```
Select from Tab where idTag= 10 and type='Personne'
```

will use the index automatically

Comment: if I do Select from Tab where index_idTag= 10 I have 0 result end if I do the same query which not the index Select from Tab where idTag= 10 I have 3 result. if I query on Tab I dont see my index and if I query on index (select from INDEX:index_idTag where key=10 ) I dont see other property

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. Can you check the rewritten query?

Comment: that will work but I use the Index (index_idTag)? or just use the property (idTag)?

Comment: It uses the index, of course. Try the same query with the index defined and without it, with thousands of records. You will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an index created and in use, you can query records in the index using the SELECT command.

Syntax:

`SELECT FROM INDEX:<index-name> WHERE key = <key>`

Example:

Selecting from the index dictionary where the key matches to Luke:

`orientdb> SELECT FROM INDEX:dictionary WHERE key='Luke'`

More information can be found in official documentation: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Indexes.html

Comment: That is work but I want to query my index (like you do + property not in the index)